# Angular 2 Quickstart install failing via npm (Link - https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html)

Tags: angularjs, ubuntu, angular, npm, npm-install

As given in the link I've been trying to get Angular 2 running on my Ubuntu 15.10 machine but I get the following error messages and the install fails.

I also tried to install Angular 2 via the npm package command, that is `sudo npm install angular2@2.0.0-alpha.32` but this gave the same sort of errors.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here are the errors. The log it mentions at the bottom can't be posted here because it is over a 1000 lines.

```
sudo npm install
npm WARN package.json angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'angular/common' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'angular2-quickstart'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-16-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/anshuman/angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/anshuman/angular2-quickstart/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must update your node and your npm for the last versions.

```
node -v
v4.4.7

npm  -v
3.10.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try to cleaar your npm cache

```
npm cache clear
```